# jQuery form validation doesn't work

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am working on a simple form validation, which simple checks whether the height field is filled in. I have double checked everything in my code but I can't find why it doesn't work.

My HTML:

```
<form id="configuration" action="">

   <div class="con_near">
      <label for="height">height: (mm)</label>
      <input id="form_height" name="height" maxlength="4" type="text" />
   </div><!--End con_near-->

   <input name="calculated" type="submit" class="submit" value="Calculate" />

</form>
```

My jQuery:

```
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){  

    // Form validation
    var configForm = $("#configuration");
    var height = $("#form_height");

    // On blur
    height.blur(validateHeight);

    // On keyup
    height.keyup(validateHeight);

    configForm.submit(function(){
        if(validateHeight())
            return true;

        else
            return false;

    });         

    function validateHeight() {
        if(height.val().length() < 4) {
            height.addClass("red_border");  
            return false;
        }
        else{
            height.removeClass("red_border");
            return true;    
        }
    }

    });

       </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lenght is not a function it is a property

try

```
configForm.submit(function(){
    if(validateHeight(height))
        return true;

    else
        return false;

});     
function validateHeight(height) {
    if(height.val().length < 4) {
        height.addClass("red_border");  
        return false;
    }
    else{
        height.removeClass("red_border");
        return true;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here `.length()`

Use

```
if(height.val().length < 4) {
```

instead of

```
if(height.val().length() < 4) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `length` in place of `length()` like,

`if(height.val().length < 4) {`

in place of

`if(height.val().length() < 4) {`

```
function validateHeight(height) {
    if(height.val().length < 4) {
    .....
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/nUeRS/)

Answer (score 0):

submit event won't stop by returning false you need to use preventDefault() to stop event try this code

```
configForm.submit(function(e){
    if(!validateHeight())
        e.preventDefault();
});         

function validateHeight() {
    if(height.val().length < 4) { // <- here you also made a mistake in length its a property not a function
        height.addClass("red_border");  
        return false;
    }
    height.removeClass("red_border");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Form validation
    var configForm = $("#configuration");
    var height = $("#form_height");

    // On blur
    height.blur(validateHeight);

    // On keyup
    height.keyup(validateHeight);

    configForm.submit(function(){
        return validateHeight();
    });

    function validateHeight() {
        if(height.val().length < 4) {
            height.addClass("red_border");
            return false;
        }
        else{
            height.removeClass("red_border");
            return true;
        }
    }

});
```